# why isn't the footer sticking to the bottom of the page?

Tags: wordpress, sticky-footer

I have tried 100 different ways to get the footer to stick to the bottom of the page.  On all my other pages, it operates fine however on one page, the footer floats to the middle.  This is the code I am trying to work but clearly something is off.

```
@media screen and (min-width : 768px) {
.page-id-94 html, body {
    display: none;
}

.site, .site-content {
    height: 100%;
}

#boldgrid-sticky-wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
}
```

}

I need this to execute in mobile/smaller screen versions only therefore I used the media query.

I am learning CSS as I go so all this is very new for me. All help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do here, but this is how I usually do my footers:

```
.footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width:100%; 
height:20%; //you can hard code a px value for this 
padding: 5px; //you may wish to change this as well
}
```

Comment: when I went to chrome developer tools page, when I remove html body from html, body, .site, .site-content, that's when the footer moved to the bottom of the page, like I wanted it to so I used that as a guide to writing how I needed it to formulate.  Used #colophon as the class

Comment: what you provided isn't working.  This is what I am struggling with, I cannot figure out what class to use and what selectors.